# How to add a calibre bookmark txt to manifest

Tags: epub, calibre, smashwords

I converted my docx into a epub file using Calibre but Smashwords is saying that the META-INF/calibre_bookmarks.txt file is not listed in the manifest.

Below is their full explanation. Does anyone know how to easily add this?

```
File 'META-INF/calibre_bookmarks.txt' in EPUB not listed in manifest!
Your .epub file is missing one or more elements in its manifest. A complete manifest is required for distribution to Apple. Here's how Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) defines "Manifest":"The manifest element lists all the files contained in the package. Each file is represented by an item element, and has the attributes id, href, media-type. All XHTML (content documents), stylesheets, images or other media, embedded fonts, and the NCX file should be listed here."
```

Comment: If you're trying to publish, I'd say that the `calibre_bookmarks.txt` file shouldn't included *at all*. AFAIK, it's only used by the Calibre Viewer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Smashwords has approved the file, so it must've been something on their end because I didn't do anything. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit this myself trying to put a book on Smashwaords. It seems that browsing a book with Calibre adds an extra file called 'calibre_bookmarks.txt'. (Smashwords spots it, but the IDPF's Epub Validator doesn't!)

The solution's simple enough:

1. Change the book's extension from .epub to .zip. (Eg: mybook.epub ->
   mybook.zip)
2. Open the .zip file.
3. Delete the 'calibre_bookmarks.txt' file.
4. Save and close the .zip.
5. Rename it back to .epub.

Alternative method: Don't open your books in Calibre ;-)

Comment: A million thanks. You just rescued my book process!